# Adding watermark to a video by using ffmpeg in php

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I created a video with group of images and mp3.
But i want to add a watermark text to that video .i am using the below code to add the text.

```
exec('/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -y -i output.mov -acodec libmp3lame -vcodec msmpeg4 \
-b:a 192k -b:v 1000k -ar 44100 \
-vf "drawtext=text=string1 string2 string3 string4 string5 string6 string7 :expansion=normal:fontfile=/usr/bin/DejaVuSerif-BoldItalic-webfont.ttf: y=0:x=h-(2*lh)-n: fontcolor=white: fontsize=40: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000000@1" \
-an IMG_0696.avi');
```

The issue with this is that the video file is creating with zero size.
Can any one help me please.
Or else Suggest me any other command to add watermark text to video.
Thank you in advance...

Comment: Does that command at the console work?

Comment: I am not sure, but its working fine in php.

Comment: Not sure I am with you. If it is working in PHP, what's the question? `:)`

Comment: that command to creating video with 0 size.I am not sure that will work in console because i haven't tried in console.

Comment: So, not working in PHP then. OK, at the risk of stating the obvious, try it on the console?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.But i am not familiar with console.And i am running in the live server.

Comment: You absolutely need to be working on a dev server - can you get this set up? If you are using Windows locally, set up a virtual computer using something like VirtualBox and install Linux inside it.

Comment: even if it will work in console, it will not be much useful for me.Because i need to include that command inthe php program which will make the dynamic creation of video

Comment: Yes indeed. But you need to get it working on the console first before you try running it in PHP. What you are doing in PHP is essentially running a console command.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39197/discussion-between-surya-peddada-and-halfer)

Answer (score 3):

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex overlay output.mp4
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using php-ffmpeg [Below : Composer Json]:

```
{
    "require": {
        "php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg": "^0.6.1"
    }
}
```

and Using this php-ffmpeg library you can add watermark's using the following codes:

```
<?php

function processVideo($videoSource,$reqExtension, $watermark = "")
{
    $ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();

    $video = $ffmpeg->open($videoSource);

    $format = new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('libmp3lame', 'libx264');

    if (!empty($watermark))
    {
        $video  ->filters()
                ->watermark($watermark, array(
                    'position' => 'relative',
                    'top' => 25,
                    'right' => 50,
                ));
    }

    $format
    -> setKiloBitrate(1000)
    -> setAudioChannels(2)
    -> setAudioKiloBitrate(256);

    $randomFileName = rand().".$reqExtension";
    $saveLocation = getcwd(). '/video/'.$randomFileName;
    $video->save($format, $saveLocation);

    if (file_exists($saveLocation))
        return "http://localhost/test/video/$randomFileName";
    else
        return "http://localhost/test/thumb/404.png";

}

echo $videoLocation =  processVideo("sample.mp4","mp4","favicon.png");

?>
```

[Please, update the location according to your need.]

Answer (score 1):

Command:

```
    ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex 'overlay' output.mp4
```

Try this code in your controller.

```
  public function setWaterMark(Request $request_body){
      try {
        $watermark = Input::file('watermark');
        $input = Input::file('input');

        ffmpeg = "C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg";
        $cmd = $ffmpeg . " -i " . $input . " -i " . $watermark . " -filter_complex 'overlay' " . $output_file;
        exec($cmd, $output);

        return $output_file;
  }
```

Comment: This worked dear, but how can we set position of watermark image. eg. i have to set it top right position. How can we do it? Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

```
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
$video = $ffmpeg->open('video.mpg');
$video
    ->filters()
    ->resize(new FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(320, 240))
    ->synchronize();
$video
    ->frame(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(10))
    ->save('frame.jpg');
$video
    ->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264(), 'export-x264.mp4')
    ->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\WMV(), 'export-wmv.wmv')
    ->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\WebM(), 'export-webm.webm');
```

Steps for install FFmpeg on system.
http://drupalasia.com/article/how-add-watermark-video-using-php-and-ffmpeg