# Watermark mp4/m4v in PHP

Tags: php, mp4, watermark, m4v

Is there a way to watermark mp4/m4v files in PHP? The files are already saved on the server, but when displaying, I want a watermark to be put over through PHP (header-output).

Here is my current PHP code:

```
$fp = fopen($path, 'rb');

// Change the header to whatever your file's mime type is
header("Content-Type: " . $ctype);
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($path));

fpassthru($fp);
exit;
```

Comment: You would likely need to pre-process the video(s) and add your watermark.

Comment: Using exec and ffmpeg:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356963/adding-watermark-to-a-video-by-using-ffmpeg-in-php

Comment: Thanks. How would that be implemented into my code? See edit

Comment: Depending on the specs of the server and demand, re-encoding all files on the fly could be a timely process, optimally, you should pre-process the files as @JonathanKuhn suggested. Even if you were to save the files so that you ensured old videos weren't re-encoded you still have to put up with new files and the overhead on the server. Your question implies you would be OKAY with an overlay. Are my assumptions correct?

Comment: I guess overlay is fine - it doesn't really matter - but it has to played in fullscreen. So a simple HTML overlay doesn't fit in here... but maybe some other video plugins will solve it, or what are you thinking?

Comment: I found a solution that works.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234740/overlay-on-html5-fullscreen-video