# Streaming a video using PHP and manipulating it using FFMPEG

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, streaming

I use the class in [this tutorial](https://codesamplez.com/programming/php-html5-video-streaming-tutorial) to open a mp4 file  in PHP and stream it to HTML5 video player and everything works fine. Now I would like to do some manipulations to the stream on the fly. e.g: adding a watermark to the stream. I am not sure if it can be done using ffmpeg command or [PHP-FFMpeg](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg).

The class in the mentioned tutorial opens the file (or the range of the file that is needed by the player), into the $data variable:

```
        $data = fread($this->stream, $bytesToRead);
        echo $data;
        flush();
```

I guess I need to pass the $data to ffmpeg somehow, add the watermark and then echo() the manipulated $data instead of the original one. But I am not sure if it's possible or not, and if it is, how it can be done? I don't know how to open a variable in ffmpeg instead of a file and how to get the output as a variable, and not a file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your need to do it in ffmpeg, search [`add watermark to ffmpeg`](https://www.google.com/search?q=add+watermark+to+ffmpeg+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding watermark to a video by using ffmpeg in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356963/adding-watermark-to-a-video-by-using-ffmpeg-in-php)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thank you but that is not what I want to do. I want to read a file, watermark it on the fly, and stream it.

Comment: @Lounis thank you, bot no. I want to read a file, watermark it on the fly, and stream it.

Comment: yes that's what ffmpeg does, if you want to do in PHP code then you are going to be disappointed

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I want to do it using ffmpeg. but I want the PHP to open the file, pass the file data to ffmpeg for manipulation, get the output from ffmpeg an stream it. That's totally different with the normal usage of ffmpeg.

Comment: Do you already know the ffmpeg command you want to use?